# How to implement Handlebar conditional header

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, handlebars.js, frontend

Layout (**default.hbs**):

```
{{> header}}

{{> body}}

{{> footer}}
```

**Header.hbs** 
Containers the header with navigation

**Achieve:** 
I do not want to show navigation in search page

Please let me know how can i achieve the conditional header, where i can display normal header in all pages and without navigation in my search page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass in a variable to identify the page as being the search page, then use that in a conditional statement to render the header or not. A bit like this:

```
{{#unless isSearchPage}}
    {{> header}}
{{/unless}}

{{> body}}

{{> footer}}
```